# One-to-one matching of two data frame by ID

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to combine this two table by their ID and match corresponding amount (one-to-to match)

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c("101","101","101", "102","102","102","102"),
               authno=c("A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C", "D"),
               amount=c(1083, 1329, 1083, 1330, 1330, 1330, 140))

df2 <- data.frame(id=c("101","101","101","102", "102","102","102"),
               amount=c(1329, 833, 1083, 1330, 1330, 1700, 120))
```

This is my desired result:

```
id  authno amount
101  A  1083
101  B  1328
101  C  NA
102  A  1330
102  B  1330
102  C  NA
102  D  NA
```

Note that since there is only 1 row in `df2` with `id == 101 & amount == 1083`, only the first row that matches that (`authno == A`) will match, while the second instance (`authno == C`) gets an `NA`. Since there are 2 rows in `df2` with `id == 102 & amount == 1330`, authno A and B can match, while C cannot.

Comment: You may need `merge` after creating a sequence column by 'id'

Comment: Can I get a sample code to that @akrun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine there might be a more efficient way of doing this, but `dplyr` can handle this:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id, amount) %>% 
  arrange(authno) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% 
              group_by(id, amount) %>% 
              mutate(row = row_number(),
                     present_in_both = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(amount = if_else(is.na(present_in_both),
                          NA_real_,
                          amount)) %>% 
  select(-present_in_both, -row)
```

As you can see, I'm grouping `id` and `amount` in each dataframe, and then adding a dummy grouping ID as `row`.  The `left_join` will match all `id`, `amount`, and `row`.  In your case, `id == 101 & amount == 1083` happens twice in `df1` but only once in `df2`, so this set-up will only allow the match once!

Next, we remove the `amount` if there was no match in the `left_join` (marked with `present_in_both`.  Finally, we remove our two dummy variables `row` and `present_in_both`.

Which gives:

```
  id    authno amount
  <fct> <fct>   <dbl>
1 101   A        1083
2 101   B        1329
3 101   C          NA
4 102   A        1330
5 102   B        1330
6 102   C          NA
7 102   D          NA
```